# Center rectangle in another rectangle

Tags: .net, vb.net, drawing, rectangles

I have not been able to establish a really reliable code to center a rectangle in another rectangle.

I would like to have the "RectangleToCenter"'s center point match the "SourceRectangle"'s center point.
No scaling should be involved.

My current attempt is

```
Public Sub CenterRect(ByVal uMain As Rectangle, ByRef uRectToCenter As Rectangle)

    Dim iAVHeightHalf As Integer = uMain.Height / 2 'src y center
    Dim iAVWidthHalf As Integer = uMain.Width / 2 'src x center

    Dim iStartDestX As Integer = uMain.Left + (uRectToCenter.Width / 2) - iAVWidthHalf
    Dim iStartDestY As Integer = uMain.Top + (uRectToCenter.Height / 2) - iAVHeightHalf

    Dim nNewStart As New Point(iStartDestX, iStartDestY)

    uRectToCenter.Location = nNewStart

End Sub
```

But it does not look clean to me.

Comment: The code doesn't look clean, or the result is not what you want?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If the first rectangle has coordinates (x1, y1), width (w1), and height (h1), the second rectangle should look as such:

```
w2 = //whatever you want the width to be
h2 = //whatever you want the height to be
x2 = x1 + ((w1 - w2) / 2);
y2 = y1 + ((h1 - h2) / 2);
```

Hopefully this pseudo-code helps. This is mostly a math question.

Answer (score 0):

```
    objSmall.X = CInt(objBig.X + (Math.Round(((objBig.Width / 2) - (objSmall.Width / 2)), 0)))
    objSmall.Y = CInt(objBig.Y + (Math.Round(((objBig.Height / 2) - (objSmall.Height / 2)), 0)))
```

Comment: doesn't this only take into account the width and height, and not the location of the object on screen?

Answer (score 0):

As an extension method:

```
public static Point CenterInRectangle(this Size Inner, Rectangle Outer)
{
    return new Point()
    {
        X = Outer.X + ((Outer.Width - Inner.Width) / 2),
        Y = Outer.Y + ((Outer.Height - Inner.Height) / 2)
    };
}
```